# How to tell if iTunes in the mini player mode from applescript

Tags: macos, itunes, applescript

Is there a way to tell if iTunes is in mini player mode from applescript?

Using Mac OS X 10.8.4 Mountain lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        if title of window 1 is "MiniPlayer" then
            -- If mini player
        else if title of window 1 is not "MiniPlayer" then
            -- if big player 
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: This works the way expected if either the MiniPlayer or the main window are visible.  That is, if one or the other, but not both, are visible.  However, if both windows are visible, it always acts as though MiniPlayer is window 1.  Maybe it is, but it would be nice to know which window is active (has focus).